# Tangent surface of a twisted cubic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

I am trying to describe the tangent surface to a twisted cubic curve $C$, i.e. the curve which is given parametrically by $t\mapsto(t, t^2, t^3)$. This surface $S$ is given parametrically by $(t,u)\mapsto(t+u, t^2+2tu, t^3+3t^2u)$. Denote $x=t+u$, $y=t^2+2tu$, $z=t^3+3t^2u$. What is the polynomial equation of $S$ in terms of $x,y,z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best solved with Gröbner bases

```
nmajo@laureline:~$ /usr/bin/M2
Macaulay2, version 1.7
with packages: ConwayPolynomials, Elimination, IntegralClosure, LLLBases, PrimaryDecomposition, ReesAlgebra, TangentCone

i1 : R=QQ[t,u,x,y,z]

o1 = R

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : I=ideal(x-(t+u), y-(t^2+2*t*u), z-(t^3+3*t^2*u))

                            2                3     2
o2 = ideal (- t - u + x, - t  - 2t*u + y, - t  - 3t u + z)

o2 : Ideal of R

i3 : gens gb I

o3 = | t+u-x u2-x2+y 2uy2+xy2-2uxz-2x2z+yz uxy-x2y+2y2-uz-xz 2ux2-2x3-2uy+3xy-z 3x2y2-4x3z-4y3+6xyz-z2 |

             1       6
o3 : Matrix R  <--- R
```

The last entry in the gröbner basis is independent of t and u, and is your equation $3x^2y^2-4x^3z-4y^3+6xyz-z^2$

[Here](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/courses/535/535-f02/math535.html) is a gif.

Comment: Can you give a little explanation of the algorithm in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: @vitaliy: Cox Little and O'Shea: _Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms_ is a good place to start learning about Gröbner bases. You need a monomial ordering, and then a Gröbner basis is a basis where all leading terms of things in the ideal appear as leading terms of the basis, basically you add elements to your basis so that it's not minimal anymore to get this. Buchberger's algorithm is to add certain combinations of things in the ideal called S-polynomials to your starting basis (the one you gave) until all such further combinations become zero. Macaulay2 uses monomial order revlex unless told.

Comment: Thank you for a refference! This problem about twisted cubic is discussed there.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative description is that (x,y,z) belongs to the tangent surface if and only if the polynomial (in the variable $s$) $1+3sx+3s^2y+s^3z$ has a double root.
The corresponding M2 commands to get the equation of the tangent surface are

R=QQ[s,x,y,z]

factor (discriminant(1+3*s*x+3*s^2*y+s^3*z,t))

The reason is that the twisted cubic corresponds to polynomials $p(t)=(1+st)^3$ and the tangent line at $p(t)$ is parametrized by cubic polynomials
$p(t)+up'(t)=(1+st)^2(1+(t+3u)s)$.

Answer (score 1):

I used Mathematica to eliminate $u$ and $t$, and I got
$$4x^3z - 3x^2y^2 - 6xyz + 4y^3 + z^2 = 0$$

The command is simply

```
Eliminate[{x = t + u, y = t^2 + 2*t*u, z = t^3 + 3*t*t*u}, {t,u}]
```

You can use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eliminate%5B%7Bx%3Dt%2Bu%2C%20y%3Dt%5E2%2B2*t*u%2C%20z%3Dt%5E3%20%2B%203*t*t*u%7D%2C%20%7Bt%2Cu%7D%5D) if you don't have access to Mathematica. I don't know what algorithm is used internally, but I would guess that it's probably Groebner bases.