# Tangential space to the rational normal curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, surfaces, projective-geometry, intersection-theory

**Exercise 15.5** *(Harris, Algebraic Geometry: A First Course)*: Describe the tangential surface to the twisted cubic curve $C \subset \mathbb P^3$. In particular, show that it is a quartic surface. What is its singular locus?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200823/tangent-surface-of-a-twisted-cubic-curve) the answer is given: $3x^2y^2-4x^3z-4y^3w+6xyzw-z^2w^2$ for $(w,x,y,z)=(1,t,t^2,t^3)$. Clearly, it is a *quartic* curve, and one can calculate its singular locus directly – it *coincides* with the twisted cubic curve itself.

But it does not explain anything. How to prove it *without calculations*? **And what happens with the tangential space to the rational normal curve in $\mathbb P^n$ if $n>3$?**

Comment: From hints to exercises: This can be ground out directly; one shortcut might be to realize ${\Bbb P}^3$ as the space of homogeneous cubic polynomials in two variables mod scalars, the twisted as the locus of cubes (as in Lecture 10) and show that the tangential surface $TC$ is the zero locus of the discriminant.

Answer (score 4):

It's not hard to determine *parametric* equations for the surface.  We have
$$x(t) = t, \qquad y(t) = t^2, \qquad z(t) = t^3,$$
so
$$x'(t) = 1, \qquad y'(t) = 2t, \qquad z'(t) = 3t^2;$$
therefore, the tangent line to a point $(t, t^2, t^3)$ is
$$(t, t^2, t^3) + s(1, 2t, 3t^2),$$
and consequently the surface $S$ consisting of all such lines is parametrized by
$$x(t,s) = t+ s, \qquad y(t,s) = t^2 + 2 s t, \qquad z(t,s) = t^3 + 3 s t^2.$$

(If you look at the answers to the question you linked, you can see that these equations were given as input to the computer.)

Implicitizing a set of parametric equations by hand is not straightforward.  However, the problem doesn't ask for an implicit equation; it just asks to indicate the surface (which we've done) and compute the singular locus.

But a having a parametrization instead of implicit equations actually makes it *easier* to determine where a surface is singular.  In particular,

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = 1, \qquad \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} = 1,$$
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = 2t + 2s, \qquad \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} = 2t,$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = 3t^2+6st, \qquad \frac{\partial z}{\partial s} = 3t^2,$$

so the tangent space to the surface $S$ at the point $\big(x(t,s), y(t,s), z(t,s)\big)$ is spanned by the vectors

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2t + 2s \\
3t^2 + 6st \end{bmatrix} \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2t \\
3t^2\end{bmatrix}$$

By definition, $S$ is singular at $\big(x(s,t), y(s,t), z(s,t)\big)$ if the tangent space to $S$ at that point is less-than-two dimensional.  Clearly neither vector can be zero, so the only way this can happen is if one is a scalar multiple of the other.  Since both have the same first coordinate, this can only happen if they're equal.  And then it's easy to see that this happens only when $s = 0$, i.e. the singular locus of $S$ is the twisted cubic itself.

**UPDATE**: I see that the problem also asks to show that $S$ is a quartic surface.  If you have an appropriately general version of Bezout's theorem, you can do this by finding a line that meets $S$ transversally at exactly four points, though I don't immediately see a nice choice of line you could use.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for the answer, but could you explain why the singular locus is *equal* to the twisted cubic, not *contained* in it?

Comment: If $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2t + 2s \\
3t^2 + 6st \end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2t \\
3t^2\end{bmatrix}$$
then, looking at the first column, we have $\lambda = 1$, so it follows that $2t + 2s = 2t$ and $3t^2 + 6st = 3t^2$.  Cancelling, we have $2s = 0$ and $6 s t = 0$, which has the solution $s = 0$.

Comment: Daniel, but you can parametrize smooth variety unsmoothly, such as $x=0$ on the plane via $x=0, y=t^2,$, so there is necessary to use some nontrivial argument.

Answer (score 1):

Beltrametti, Carletti, Gallarati, Bragadin [*Lectures on Curves, Surfaces and Projective Varieties: A Classical View of Algebraic Geometry*](http://books.google.com/books?id=g9DBgD22n_IC) p 227-8:

> Let $C$ be an irreducible non-planar cubic in ${\Bbb P}^3$ [..]for each point of ${\Bbb P}^3$ there passes one and only one chord (or a tangent) of $C$ , and write the equation for the ruled surface of the tangents to $C$ [..] :
>
> For a point not belonging to a cubic $C$ there can not pass more than one chord of the curve, because otherwise $C$ would lie in the plane of two concurrent chords (since that plane has at least four intersections with $C$ ). The chords of $C$ (which are in number $\infty^2$) can not fill merely a surface, because in that case through each point of that surface there would have to pass infinitely many (i.e., the $\infty^1$ determined by passage through the point). On the other hand, a surface that contains all the chords of a curve would also have to contain all the cones that project the curve from one of its points, and the curve would be planar.
>   This fact can be derived analytically in the following fashion. Let $C$ be the locus of the point $P(t) =[t^3,t^2,t,1]$ and $O = [a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3]$ a point not belonging to $C$. If $P(\lambda)$ and $P(\mu)$ are two points of the curve $C$ which are collinear with $O$, the matrix
>
> \begin{pmatrix}a_0&a_1&a_2&a_3\\\lambda^3&\lambda^2&\lambda&1\\\mu^3&\mu^2&\mu&1\end{pmatrix}
>
> has rank two. Hence
>
> $$\begin{vmatrix}a_0&a_1&a_2\\\lambda^3&\lambda^2&\lambda\\\mu^3&\mu^2&\mu\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}a_1&a_2&a_3\\\lambda^2&\lambda&1\\\mu^2&\mu&1\end{vmatrix}=0$$
>
> That is,
>   $$ a_0-a_1(\lambda+\mu)+a_2\lambda\mu=0 $$
>   $$ a_1-a_2(\lambda+\mu)+a_3\lambda\mu=0$$
>   This implies that  and  are the roots of the quadratic equation
>
> $$\begin{vmatrix}x^2&x&1\\a_0&a_1&a_2\\a_1&a_2&a_3\end{vmatrix}=0 (*)$$
>
> Thus for each point $O$ not belonging to $C$ there passes one and only one chord of $C$ . The trace $P'$ of this chord upon a plane $\pi$ not passing through $O$ is the double point of the cubic $\Gamma$, the projection of $C$ from $O$ onto $\pi$.
>   If the roots of (*) coincide, that is, if O is a point of the quartic surface with equation
>   $$(x_0x_3-x_1x_2)^2-4(x_0x_2-x_1^2)(x_1x_3-x_2^2)= 0 (**)$$ 
>   one has a tangent rather than a chord of $C$ (at the point $P(\lambda)=P(\mu)$) and $P'$ is a cusp of $\Gamma$.
>
> Equation (**) is the equation of the ruled surface F of the tangents of $C$ . From it one sees that a space cubic has rank 4, which means that four is the number of tangents of the cubic supported by a generic line (in the four points in which the line intersects the quartic $F$).

To what happens when $n > 3$: [Eisenbud](http://www.msri.org/~de/papers/pdfs/1992-007.pdf) finds the quadrics in the ideal of the tangent developable surface to the rational normal curve (which generate the ideal from $n\geq 6$).

He writes

> The following construction was noted by Buchweitz and Schreyer some time around 1983: One way to get a canonical curve of genus $g$ is to take a rational curve with $g$ cusps in ${\Bbb P}^{g-1}$. Such curves turn out to be the hyperplane sections of an arithmetically Cohen-Macaulay surface (actually a degenerate K3 surface, if there are any geometers listening) obtained as the tangent developable surface ($\equiv$ the union of the tangent lines) to the rational normal curve in ${\Bbb P}^g$