# Geometric Interpretation of existence of a trivial subrepresentation inside $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbb{C} $-rep $ \text{Sym}^4(\text{Sym}^3 V))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $V \cong \mathbb{C}^2$ be the standard representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbb{C} $ ragarded as subalgebra inside $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{C})$.  We follow the convention from Fulton & Harris' Representation Theory book and choose as generators for $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbb{C}$ the matrices $H, X,Y$ given on page 147 and so we obtain the eigenvalue/ weight decomposition $V= V_{-1} \bigoplus V_1= \mathbb{C} \cdot y \oplus \mathbb{C} \cdot x$ with respect to the both weights (here also eigenvalues) $1,-1$ of the generator $H$ of the Cartan algebra.

Thinking about $x$ and $y$ as polynomials allows to give a natural interpretation to symmetric powers $\text{Sym}(V)$ as vector space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in $x$ and $y$.

The Exercise 11.24. on page 158 asks the reader to analyze the induced representation $ \text{Sym}^4(\text{Sym}^3 V))$ and to show that it contains in it's decomposition in irreducible pieces a trivial one-dimensional subrepresentation $V_0 \cong \mathbb{C}$.

Then it is remarked that the fact that in the decomposition of $ \text{Sym}^4(\text{Sym}^3 V))$ occurs the trivial one-dimensional subrepresentation, gives an interesting geometric interpretation. Namely, to say that $ \text{Sym}^4(\text{Sym}^3 V))$ has such an invariant one-dimensional subspace is to say that there exists a quartic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3 \cong \mathbb{P}(\text{Sym}^3 V)$ preserved under all motions of $\mathbb{P}^3$ carrying the rational normal curve
$C$ into itself.

This part I not understand. In §11.3, page 153 there is explained how to think about rational normal curve as subset
$C= \{[v \cdot v \cdot ... \cdot v] : v \in V\} $ inside $ \mathbb{P}(\text{Sym}^n V) \cong \mathbb{P}^n$. But how to use the existence of the trivial one-dimensional subrepresentation of $ \text{Sym}^4(\text{Sym}^3 V))$ to conclude the existence of the quartic surface inside $\mathbb{P}(\text{Sym}^3 V)$? Why is it a quartic?

Moreover the text claims that one can say explicitely what this surface is: The answer is simple: it is the tangent
developable to the twisted cubic, that is, the surface given as the union of the
tangent lines to $C$. How all these amazing conclusions can be drawn just from the existence of this trivial one-dimensional subrepresentation in the decomposition of  $\mathbb{P}(\text{Sym}^3 V)$?

Comment: An element of $\operatorname{Sym}^4(\operatorname{Sym}^3(V))$ are in correspondence with quartics in $\mathbb{P}^3$. A one-dimensional subrepresentation is equivalent to giving an element that is invariant under the induced $\mathfrak s\mathfrak l _2$-action, which corresponds to the projective automorphisms of $\mathbb P^3$ carrying the rational normal curve to itself

Comment: As far as why it is the tangent developable to the twisted cubic, I would argue saying that the tangent developable to the twisted cubic, which is quartic, is preserved by all automorphisms that preserve the twisted cubic, clearly, and since there is only one 1-dimensional subrepresentation of $\operatorname{Sym}^4(\operatorname{Sym}^3(V))$, they must be the same

Comment: This is because the discriminant of a binary cubic form is of degree 4 in the coefficients of the cubic.

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez: You mentioned in your argumentation that the tangent developable of the twisted curve (ie informally the union of tangent lines) is a quartic. How to see it?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: I not understand what is this "binary cubic form" of which 
you take the discriminant and obtain a degree $4$ equation
in it's coefficients? How does it arise in this construction? Recall, as Aitor noticed an element of 
$\operatorname{Sym}^4(\operatorname{Sym}^3(V))$ corresponds
(up to scalar) to a quartic 
in $\mathbb{P}^3= \mathbb{P}(\text{Sym}^3(V))$ and
a one-dimensional subrep to a quartic 
invariant under the $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-action, where 
the action is the linear action on $\text{Sym}^3(V)$ (and 
therefore on $\mathbb{P}^3$) induced from action on $V$.

Comment: The $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-invariant quartic $Q(\underline{X})$
has the form 
$\sum_{\hat{k} \in \mathbb{N}^4} a_{\hat{k}} \underline{X}^{\hat{k}}$ 
(where $\underline{X}=(X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3)$ and 
$\underline{X}^{\hat{k}}:= X_0^{k_0} \cdot X_1^{k_1} \cdot 
X_2^{k_2} \cdot X_3^{k_3} \cdot $ for $\hat{k}=(k_0,k_1,k_2, k_3)$.
A $S \in \mathfrak{sl}_2$ acts on the quartic by 
precomposition in argument $Q(\underline{X}) \mapsto 
Q(S(\underline{X}))$. I not see which binary cubic form you are considering. Could you explain how you obtain this binary cubic you are refering to in your comment above?

Comment: I think this is something you get from finding equations for the tangent developable: $3x^2y^2-4x^3z-4y^3+6xyz-z^2$ (in $\mathbb A^3$) and it has of course degree 4. There are other MSE posts that talk about this.

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez: I see, eg [here ](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206360/tangential-space-to-the-rational-normal-curve) . But it seems to be rather "accidental" that that it works so "easily" for rational normal curves. Namely the method Jan-Magnus Økland applied works only in rather special case and cannot be conceptionally generalized to broad classes of varieties. So in general even if we work in "classical" setting (with old fashioned varieties over complex numbers) there is no general "conceptional" strategy to calculate the vanishing equations of tangent developable?

Comment: An element of ${\rm Sym^3(V)}$ is a binary cubic. If $W=\mathbb{C}^2$ and $V=W^{\vee}$, then ${\rm Sym^3(V)}$ can be identified with the space of homogeneous polynomial functions on $W$ of degree three. These are called binary (two variables) cubic (degree three) forms (homogeneous polynomials).

Comment: Now the discriminant should strictly speaking be in ${\rm Sym}^4(({\rm Sym^3}(V))^{\vee})$. However, $sl_2$ reps are self dual so you can get rid of the "$\vee$" symbols everywhere.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: I think I understand your explanantion now. When we regard ${\rm Sym^3(V)}$ as the space homogeneous polynomials of degree $3$ two variables, then above you identify each such element $a_{30}W_0^3+a_{21}W_0^2W_1+a_{12}W_0W_1^2+a_{03}W_1^3$ as vector $(a_{30}, a_{21}, a_{12}, a_{03})$ with entries= coefficients of the polynomial. Then ${\rm Sym}^4(({\rm Sym^3}(V))^{\vee})$ is reinterpreted as space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $4$
in variables $Z_{30}, Z_{21}, Z_{12}, Z_{03})$.

Comment: In other words the elements of 
${\rm Sym}^4(({\rm Sym^3}(V))^{\vee})$ receive as arguments $Z_{30}, Z_{21}, Z_{12}, Z_{03})$ the coefficients $(a_{30}, a_{21}, a_{12}, a_{03})$ of the vectors from ${\rm Sym^3(V)}$. For example as you said the discriminant is such an element beeing quadratic in coefficients of binary cubic forms, which has moreover the special feature to be additionally $sl_2$, I see now your argument, thank you for explanantion.

Comment: One interesting observation: having established that the trivial subrep of ${\rm Sym}^4(({\rm Sym^3}(V))^{\vee})$ corresponds to a quartic in $\mathbb{P}^3$ invariant under $sl_2$-action, it becomes relatively easy to show that this quartic is even the tangent developable to the twisted cubic curve: We know by construction it contains the twisted cubic curve, it has dimension $2$.

Comment: From dimensional reasons to show that it is the tangent developable we only have to show that (1) it contains every tangent line of the twisted cubic curve (easy explicit calculation) + (2) that the quartic is irreducible. Do you see an argument why the discriminant cannot be written as product of two homogeneous polynomials both of degree $\ge1$?

Comment: @user267839: you are asking about the irreducibility of the discriminant. This is true. For an elementary proof see the answer by Robert Bryant at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221739/irreducibility-of-discriminant