# Two statements related to tangent developables

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

There are two statements about [tangent developables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_developable) at this [website](https://www.mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/devellopabledestangentes/devellopabledestangentes.shtml):

> 1. A space curve is algebraic iff its associated developable also is.
> 2. The algebraic developable surfaces (other than the cones and cylinders) of lowest degree are of degree 4, and they are the
>      developables associated to the skew cubic curves.

**Question:**

1. Are these statements true?
2. If these statements are true, are there known proofs of these statements?

Comment: For the tangent developable of the twisted cubic [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200823/tangent-surface-of-a-twisted-cubic-curve/1232800#1232800).