# Surface defined as an image of a morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Let
$$\phi:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^3\;,\;(s,t)\to(s+t,s^2+2st,s^3+3s^2t)$$
I have to prove that the image of this morphism is the surface $M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{C}^3: 4x^3z-3x^2y^2-6xyz+4y^3+z^2=0\}$.

My work:

Take $f(x,y,z)=4x^3z-3x^2y^2-6xyz+4y^3+z^2\in\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$, and lets name $I=\phi(\mathbb{C}^2)$. If $(x,y,z)\in I$ then exists some $(s,t)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ such as $x=s+t$, $y=s^2+2st$ and $z=s^3+3s^2t$. Plugging those values into $f$ we can see that $f(x,y,z)=0$ and since $M=Z(f)$ we have that $I\subset M$. But now I'm stuck at proving the reciprocal, $M\subset I$. Any help is welcomed!

Thanks

The question appears in the book *Divisibilidad en anillos conmutativos* by J.M. Gamboa. This is a basic book about rings with a little introduction to polynomial rings, so I think that we should not need to use the material [in this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200823/tangent-surface-of-a-twisted-cubic-curve) to prove the claim.

Comment: This can be viewed as the [tangent developable surface of the twisted cubic curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200823/tangent-surface-of-a-twisted-cubic-curve)

Comment: Im not very familiar with those terms, the excercise is in a basic ring theory book so there must be another way

Comment: Just don't expect it to be easy: $(2s^2tx^2+8st^2x^2+2s^2x^3+4stx^3-2s^2ty-8st^2y-3s^2xy-8stxy-2sx^2y-4tx^2y-2x^3y+4sy^2+4ty^2+4xy^2+s^2z+4stz-2sxz-2x^2z)(x-s-t)+(-4t^2x^2+2tx^3+2x^4+4t^2y-x^2y-4y^2-2tz+3xz)(y-s^2-2st)+(-2tx^2-2x^3+2ty+3xy-z)(z-s^3-3s^2t)=3x^2y^2-4x^3z-4y^3+6xyz-z^2$

Comment: What's the problem with the link? I would have thought that this answers the question. Can you be specific about what more you're looking for with the bounty?

Comment: A way to prove it without the contents of the link, because is an excercise in an undergraduate book of ring theory

Comment: Which book? It's very strongly encouraged to include information like that in questions here. (Also, if you don't use [@replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) folks may not get notifications for your responses - for instance, I did not get notified of you last comment.)

Comment: @KReiser edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$
\phi_1(s,t)=s+t, \
\phi_2(s,t)=s^2+2st, \
\phi_3(s,t)=s^3+3s^2t \tag{1}
$$

You have already checked that

$$
f(\phi_1(s,t),\phi_2(s,t),\phi_3(s,t)) = 0 \tag{2}
$$

Conversely, let $(x,y,z)\in{\mathbb C}^3$ such that $f(x,y,z)=0$.

Now, consider $g(s)=\phi_2(s,x-s)$. Then

$$g(s)=s^2+2s(x-s)-y=2sx-s^2-y=-(s^2-2sx+y) \tag{3}$$

This is a polynomial of degree exactly $2$ in $\mathbb C$, so it has two complex (possibly equal) roots $s_1$ and $s_2$ . We have $s_1+s_2=2x$ and $s_1s_2=y$. For $k=1,2$ put $t_k=x-s_k$ ; we then have

$$
\phi_1(s_k,t_k)=x, \phi_2(s_k,t_k) =y (k=1,2) \tag{4}
$$

Next, consider the polynomial $h(Z)=f(x,y,Z)$. This is a polynomial of degree $2$ in $Z$, so it has two complex (possibly equal) roots. By (2), for $k=1,2$ we have that $u_k=\phi_3(s_k,t_k)$ is a root of $h$. It is not clear at this point if $u_1$ and $u_2$ correspond to the same root of $h$ or not. We have to make some more computations to check that out. Note that
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
u_k &=& \phi_3(s_k,t_k)=s_k^2(s_k+3t_k) \\ 
&=& (2s_kx-y)(s_k+3(x-s_k)) \\
&=& -(2s_kx-y)(2s_k-3x) \\
&=& -\big(4s_k^2x-(6x^2+2y)s_k+3xy\big) \\ 
&=& -\big(4(2s_kx-y)x-(6x^2+2y)s_k+3xy\big) \\
&=& -\big((2x^2-2y)s_k-xy\big) \\ 
&=& (2y-2x^2)s_k+xy \\ 
\end{array}\tag{5}
$$

It follows that

$$u_1+u_2=(2y-2x^2)(s_1+s_2)+2xy=2x(2y-2x^2)+2xy=-4x^3+6xy \tag{6}$$

But this is exactly the opposite of the degree $1$ coefficient of $h(Z)$. It follows that the roots of $h$ are exactly $u_1$ and $u_2$ (with possibly $u_1=u_2$), so that

$$
f(x,y,Z)=(Z-u_1)(Z-u_2) \tag{7}
$$

From $f(x,y,z)=0$ we then deduce that $z=u_k=\phi_3(s_k,t_k)$ for some $k\in\lbrace 1,2 \rbrace$, which finishes the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much!